# Convergence = "closer and closer"

Tags: convergence-divergence

I am asked to find a sequence and a number such that $$|a_{n+1}-a| \lt |a_n-a|$$, but $a_n$ does not converge to a. Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$a_n=1+\dfrac1n$ and $a=0{}{}{}$.

Comment: Or any positive strictly decreasing sequence which does not converges to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any monotonically increasing (decreasing) sequence which has a limit $l$ and then pick number greater than (smaller than) $l$ for $a$.